# Ajax request in JavaScript is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

the following code is giving me troubles. It gets fired and return the right alert at the end but the ajax part is not doing anything. No error no nothing.

```
$(document).on('change', '.department_select', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var num = id.substring(33, 34);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= update_sub_deparments_path %>",
            data: {        
                department_id: $("#business_case_entries_attributes_0_department_id option:selected").val()       
            },
            dataType: "script",
        });

        alert(num); // Should alert the correct value (1, 3, 4 etc...)
});
```

I already tried to debug it but Im limited to the developers kit of IE8 and the console is empty. The rails logs are empty too so I really have no clue whats going wrong here.

EDIT: The script is supposed to update options for a select field by calling the update path.
EDIT2: Im using the jquery gem jquery-rails.gem (3.1.0). Not quiet sure which jquery verison this is!

EDIT3:
Okay to add more detail:

```
//routes
'/:improvement_id/business_case/update_sub_departments(.:format)', :to => 'business_cases#update_sub_departments', :as => 'update_sub_departments'

//update_sub_departments.js.erb
$('#business_case_entries_attributes_0_sub_department_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@sub_departments.collect { |sub_department| [sub_department.name.titleize, sub_department.id] })) %>");

//business_cases_controller.rb
  def update_sub_departments     
    @sub_departments = SubDepartment.where("department_id = ?", params[:department_id])      
    respond_to do |format|       
        format.js.erb     
    end
```

end

Any one knows what to do?

Regards.

**EDIT**

Okay I simplify my problem!

How do I change this part of my coffee script to normal javascript?

```
$.ajax 'update_sub_departments',       
    type: 'GET'      
    dataType: 'script'      
    data: {         
        department_id: $("#business_case_entries_attributes_0_department_id option:selected").val()         
    }
```

Comment: what is it _supposed_ to do?

Comment: Why are you limited to IE8?  Surely for debugging purposes you can try a modern browser.

Comment: Also you've got a stray trailing comma in your `$.ajax()` argument object. I don't think that'll bother anything newer than IE7 however.

Comment: Which version of Jquery do you use?

Comment: Add success and error handlers to the Ajax call and see what is happening. We can not debug server issues.

Comment: To rephrase @Matheletics question, what are you expecting to get back from the server? As @Cattwood pointed out you have no success function. I highly recommend you use `$.get` or `$.getJSON` as their structure is simpler to grok than `$.ajax`.

Comment: Well, you are only sending the request to the sever but are not doing anything with that response. How do you know that "nothing happens"?

Comment: Hmm, why am I not doing anything with the response? I call a controller function over the path and that updates the select options. And since its not doing that I think that its not doing anything. And if I put some alerts into the success function nothing will happen too.

Comment: Updating things on the backend does not magically update the clientside. It is not a full page refresh. When the Ajax call comes back, you will need to manipulte the page with JavaScript. Ajax 101

Comment: Hmm I dont really understand that. I had the script working in coffee but wanted to translate it to normal java. And the coffee script was build just like this. Worked perfectly. Not seeing the difference here. But I am a noob though.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly You need to add the success part

```
  $(document).on('change', '.department_select', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = id.substring(33, 34);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<%= update_sub_deparments_path %>",
        data: {        
            department_id: $("#business_case_entries_attributes_0_department_id option:selected").val()       
        },
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (data) {
           //Here
           alert(num); // Should alert the correct value (1, 3, 4 etc...)
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Not sure what excactly that does but tested it and still not doing it. Also tried to put the alert(num) into the success part and now the alert is not popping up too!

Comment: @user3665315 check your browser network tab (f12) and see what is sent to (and comes back from) the server when `.department_select` is changed

Comment: Thats the problem and dont see anything there. Maybe Im looking at the wrong place? The console at scripts is empty!

Comment: are you sure you have an `<input/textarea/select class="department_select"/>` ? if it is an input the change event is only fired when focus is lost, maybe you should try keypress instead of change

Comment: Hmm, since I can read the alert I would think that the event triggers well. The important html that gets created looks like this: `<select class="select optional department_select" id="business_case_entries_attributes_0_department_id" name="business_case[entries_attributes][0][department_id]">`

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the script like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.department_select', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var num = id.substring(33, 34);

        $.ajax('update_sub_departments', {
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "script",
            data: {        
                department_id: $("#business_case_entries_attributes_0_department_id option:selected").val()       
            }

        });

        alert(num) // Should alert the correct value (1, 3, 4 etc...)
});
```